# Getting Content From a Website with Java

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I was curious how to pull information from a website with Java, and I found JSoup ( HTML Parser) Was a popular suggestion. I have found quite a few examples online but nothing really explaining how to use it. Say I wanted to get the temperature for Toronto using this url, http://weather.gc.ca/city/pages/on-143_metric_e.html , how would I go about doing so?

I guess you have to specify tags, but in the html for that site, the information I want is in a  tag, but so is more inforation so when when I run my code

```
String url = "http://weather.gc.ca/city/pages/on-4_metric_e.html";
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

            String temp = document.select("dd").text();
            System.out.println("Title:  " + temp);
```

I get a lot more information than I want.

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I have played around a little but all I seem to be getting the the html code it's self.

Comment: If you want any help, you will need to post the code that you have tried thus far, and what you are having problems with. Otherwise its impossible for anyone to help you. Just asking someone to code a solution for you will not garner any answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the temperature try this:

```
String url = "http://weather.gc.ca/city/pages/on-4_metric_e.html";
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

String temp = document.select("p").get(1).text();
System.out.println("Temperature:  " + temp);
```

For formulating the CSS queries refer to the syntax sheet: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Also try: http://try.jsoup.org/, great for testing!

Comment: Can you just explain the "document.select("p").get(1).text();"

Comment: document.select("p") will extract a collection of all the <p> tags, the second in there (1 since it starts with 0) just happens to be the temperature, you should probably make a more precise query to definitively gather the temperature!

Comment: A better query would be something like: document.select("div.col-sm-12 > p:has(abbr:contains(C))").text();

Comment: I will try that out. Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Let say I want to read the contents of mywebsite.com. This is how i'll do it:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class MyClass {
  public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception {
    URL u = new URL("http://www.mywebsite.com");

    InputStream ins = u.openStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ins);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

    System.out.println(br.readLine());
  } 
}
```

Hopefully this should get you started..